# how to know if the string have ellipsize

Tags: android

i have a string in the textView as:

```
<TextView   
             android:id="@+id/comment_concent"
             android:maxLines="2"
              android:textColor="#FFCD3333"
             android:ellipsize="end"
             android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
             android:layout_width="210dip"
             android:layout_height="50dip"
             android:textSize="15sp" 
             android:text="aaddadadddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddadddddddd"/>
```

sometime the text only "addadaddad",in other words the string length is not fixed,so if the string is too long,you know the end is show"...",my question is that how to know the string if end with"...",if the string is end with"...", i will call other methods to show the whole string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Measure the text using paint object to see if it width is greater than textviews.

```
Paint paint =  new Paint();
paint.setTextSize(textView.getTextSize());
final float size = paint.measureText(textview.getText());
if ((int)size > textView.getWidth()) {
     // text is elipsized.
}
```

Edit:
Even better, just set textsize from textview instead of calculating, then measure text. Edited the above code.

Answer (score 3):

Please look into this code. This will help you.

```
 TextView textView=(TextView) yourtextviewId;
              Layout l = textView.getLayout();
                if ( l != null){
                    int lines = l.getLineCount();
                    if ( lines > 0)
                        if ( l.getEllipsisCount(lines-1) > 0)
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), textView.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
```